# Capturing ComboBox item click

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a WinForms ComboBox that remembers what items have previously been entered into it. I want a way to remove previous entries. I override the DrawItem event of the ComboBox to render the text along with an X icon. The X icon is just a square image that I scale to the height of the item. The code is pretty straight forward.

```
// Enable the owner draw on the ComboBox.
ServerComboBox.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
// Handle the DrawItem event to draw the items.
ServerComboBox.DrawItem += delegate(object cmb, DrawItemEventArgs args)
{
    // Draw the default background
    args.DrawBackground();

    String url = (String)ServerComboBox.Items[args.Index];

    // Get the bounds for the first column
    Rectangle r1 = args.Bounds;
    r1.Width -= r1.Height;

    // Draw the text
    using (SolidBrush sb = new SolidBrush(args.ForeColor))
    {
        args.Graphics.DrawString(url, args.Font, sb, r1);
    }

    // Draw the X icon
    Rectangle r2 = new Rectangle(r1.Width+1, r1.Y + 1, r1.Height - 2, r1.Height - 2);
    args.Graphics.DrawImage(Project.Test.Properties.Resources.CloseIcon, r2);
};
```

Now my issue is how to capture if the X was clicked. My first thought was to capture the MouseDown event for the ComboBox and check if the DroppedDown property was true, but that event only gets fired when you click the unexpanded ComboBox. How can I capture events from the DropDown part of the ComboBox. Once I get that, I don't think it'll be much of an issue figuring out if the X was clicked or now.

Answer (score 2):

In fact your problem is just a trivial problem which `Win32` can solve:

```
public class Form1 : Form {
  [DllImport("user32")]
  private static extern int GetComboBoxInfo(IntPtr hwnd, out COMBOBOXINFO comboInfo);
  struct RECT {
    public int left, top, right, bottom;
  }
  struct COMBOBOXINFO {
        public int cbSize;
        public RECT rcItem;
        public RECT rcButton;
        public int stateButton;
        public IntPtr hwndCombo;
        public IntPtr hwndItem;
        public IntPtr hwndList;
  }
  public Form1(){
    InitializeComponent();  
    comboBox1.HandleCreated += (s, e) => {
       COMBOBOXINFO combo = new COMBOBOXINFO();
       combo.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(combo);
       GetComboBoxInfo(comboBox1.Handle, out combo);
       hwnd = combo.hwndList;
       init = false;
    };
  }
  bool init;
  IntPtr hwnd;
  NativeCombo nativeCombo = new NativeCombo();
  //This is to store the Rectangle info of your Icons
  //Key:  the Item index
  //Value: the Rectangle of the Icon of the item (not the Rectangle of the item)
  Dictionary<int, Rectangle> dict = new Dictionary<int, Rectangle>();
  public class NativeCombo : NativeWindow {
        //this is custom MouseDown event to hook into later
        public event MouseEventHandler MouseDown;
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {                
            if (m.Msg == 0x201)//WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x201
            {                    
                int x = m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0x00ff;
                int y = m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16;
                if (MouseDown != null) MouseDown(null, new MouseEventArgs(MouseButtons.Left, 1, x, y, 0));                                                                  
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
  }
  //DropDown event handler of your comboBox1
  private void comboBox1_DropDown(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (!init) {
            //Register the MouseDown event handler <--- THIS is WHAT you want.
            nativeCombo.MouseDown += comboListMouseDown;
            nativeCombo.AssignHandle(hwnd);                
            init = true;
        }
  }
  //This is the MouseDown event handler to handle the clicked icon
  private void comboListMouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e){
    foreach (var kv in dict) {
      if (kv.Value.Contains(e.Location)) {
         //Show the item index whose the corresponding icon was held down
         MessageBox.Show(kv.Key.ToString());
         return;
      }
    }
  }
  //DrawItem event handler
  private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e) {
     //We have to save the Rectangle info of the item icons
     Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, e.Bounds.Top, e.Bounds.Height, e.Bounds.Height);
     dict[e.Index] = rect;
     //Draw the icon
     //e.Graphics.DrawImage(yourImage, rect);   
  }
}
```

**A little about what happens**

A `ComboBox` has an attached *Drop down list*, this can be accessed via its `Handle`. We use **GetComboBoxInfo** win32 api function to retrieve some info of a `ComboBox`, this info is saved in a structure called **COMBOBOXINFO**. We can get the *Handle* of the *Drop down list* via the member **hwndList** in this structure.

After having access to the *hwndList*. We can hook into its message loop using a custom **NativeWindow** class (*NativeCombo* in the example). This allows us to interfere the message loop of the *drop down list* easily. Then we can catch the **WM_LBUTTONDOWN** message to handle the *MouseDown* event. Of course, it's not a **full** *MouseDown* event, but it's just a demo and in this case it's enough to solve the problem. The **WM_LBUTTONDOWN** is sent with some info on the **clicked point** saved in *LParam*. The clicked point is calculated in the coordinates of the *Client area* of the *drop down list* (not in screen coordinates). We should notice that the **DrawItem** event handler also has **e.Bounds** argument which is also calculated in the *Client area coordinates* (not screen coordinates). Hence they are in the same *coordinates system*. We use the **Rectangle.Contains** method to know if the *clicked point* is contained in the *Bounds of some icon*. We stores all the *icon Bounds* in a **Dictionary**. So the corresponding *Key* (stores the *Item index*) of the *Rectangle* which contains the *clicked point* let us know the corresponding *Item index*, then we can process further.

Comment: All those backticks make the reading difficult.  Please use them sparingly.  `hwnd` and `ev` does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @LarsTech thank you, of course I've made a demo first before posting here, There was some code I didn't copy and paste here. Updated now.

Comment: @KingKing This works pretty well except for 1 thing. The Location coming into the comboListMouseDown seems to be incorrect. In my original post the icon is drawn into the r2 rectangle, which should be in Client coordinates, so that is the rectangle I'm saving into the dictionary. The e.Location point seems to have the correct Y value but the X is less than half of what it should be. Do you have any ideas of what I'm messing up?

Comment: @TFili I can see you have this `Rectangle r1 = args.Bounds;` in your code, that means the drawing coordinates are calculated in the same system with the coordinates of the `clicked point/ the point mouse down`. The `Dictionary<int,Rectangle>` is used to store the **Rectangles of your icon bounds**. I don't care about how you calculate the `icon bounds`, it should work. The `icon bounds` I used in my example code of course is not applicable for your case. the point is **both the drawing coordinates and clicking coordinates** are calculated in the same system (based on the drop down list).

Comment: @KingKing So the issue was in the WndProc method. X & Y are being extracted incorrectly. It won't work for really wide dropdowns (greater than 256 pixels). It should be
    int x = m.LParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff;
    int y = m.LParam.ToInt32() >> 16 & 0xffff;
I found this by looking at GET_X_LPARAM & GET_Y_LPARAM in the C++ libraries.

Answer (score 1):

When the user selects or uses mouse wheel `SelectionIndexChanged` event will fire. If you don't want to react for mouse wheel and if you need to respond only for clicking and selecting then you may consider using `SelectionChangeCommited` event.

Then you can read `SelectedIndex` or `SelectedItem` property to get the selected item.

Edit: Am sorry it seems I complelely misunderstand the question. I think you need to capture mouse down of `ListBox` inside the Combo and manually check it using `Rectange.Contains`. Will get back with more details.

Comment: What `ListBox`? If you mean the attached list box of the `ComboBox`, to get access to it, it's not simple to do with little knowledge about `win32`.

Comment: @KingKing I agree with you it is not that easy. but I can say not that hard too. I was trying for similar solution that you've given. Seems your solution will work. If not then let me give a try.

Answer (score 0):

Once the user has clicked on an item in the combo box, it becomes the selected item. You can retrieve this property from the combo box object.

Comment: this is surely not what the OP wants.

Comment: @KingKing nice challenge here. Go ahead and prove me wrong by showing you can do this in winforms.

Comment: @HighCore it's fortunately that I have a little experience about `ComboBox` in `win32`. See my answer and you may want to give me a +1.

Answer (score 0):

COMBOBOXINFO will give you that information that you can use to subclass the dropdown list window. See this for an example:

https://github.com/ehosca/MRUComboBox